# How to show a field after validateForm() is called in Drupal 8?

Tags: php, drupal, field, state, show-hide

Inside a `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` function I show or hide a field based on another checkbox field is checked or not with the following code in Drupal 8.

```
$form['field_my_url']['#states'] = [
  'visible' => [
    ':input[name="field_my_checkbox[value]"]' => ['checked' => TRUE],
  ],
];
```

In case user checks `field_my_checkbox` checkbox, enters an invalid URL in `field_my_url` and decides to uncheck `field_my_checkbox` checkbox, the `field_my_url` will then be hidden with the invalid URL remaining. It will fail the validation because the enter URL is not valid.

The user will then be redirected back with the error message. But because the `field_my_checkbox` checkbox was not checked, the `field_my_url` field will be hidden with the error message and the user cannot see that.

In this case, how can I show the `field_my_url` field if it failed the validation because it contains invalid URL in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. It might not be efficient. But it solves the problem for now, since there is no one come up with any solution on this moment. If the validation failed. I just unset the '#states' from the field. By doing this, no #states visible will be applied and the field_my_url will be show as normal.

```
unsert($form['field_my_url']['#states']);
```